# Proper time while going up in a gravitational field

Tags: special-relativity, invariants

Feynman, in his book 'Surely You're Joking, Mr. Feynman' refers to a problem he once gave one of Einstein's assistants at Princeton. The problem goes something like this:

You blast off in a rocket which has a clock on board, and there's a clock on the ground. The problem statement is that you have to be back when the clock on the ground says one hours has passed and you want it so that when you come back, your clock is as far ahead as possible.

There are mentions of the underlying idea being proper time i.e. $\tau^2 = t^2 - x^2 - y^2 - z^2$ and its property of being an invariant when talking about relativistic motion, but could someone explain **how** this invariant is the underlying concept?

Comment: There's also references of how time moves differently as you move UP in a gravitational field, could someone explain that as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In that section Feynman wasn't talking about specific facts. He was talking about his observation that some people have trouble applying knowledge they already have to new concrete cases. The person that he was asking the rocket clock question presumably knew the following facts:

1. Clocks measure proper time
2. Geodesics maximize proper time
3. Geodesics are free-fall worldlines

But when the person was asked about maximizing the difference in time between a clock on the ground and one on the rocket he didn't immediately combine those three facts to realize that they already knew the rocket answer. The maximum time difference is obtained by launching the rocket with an initial velocity such that it returns back to earth 1 hour later being in free-fall for that entire hour.